# multiple $_FILES not recognized in controller (undifined index)

Tags: php, forms, file, model-view-controller, upload

**Context :** i'm learning MVC architecture, i use a custom framework.
**issue :** my form successfully send $_POST, but $_FILES is noticed as Undefined

---

**in view :** form

```
<form action="adm/createArticle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //some inputs..
    <input name="files[]" id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
</form>
```

**action="adm/createArticle" :** the MVC prettify URLs
in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controleur=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

**in controller :**

```
public function createArticle() {
    $filesArray = $_FILES["files"];
    $this->generateView(array("filesArray" => $filesArray));
}
```

**When form is submited**

**In aimed page (createArticle.php) :**

```
// Testing
<?php var_dump($filesArray)?> // null
<?php var_dump($_POST)?>      // status 200 OK
<?php var_dump($_FILES)?>     // array (size=0) empty
```

**warning message :**

```
Notice: Undefined index: files in C:\wamp64\www\etc\Controller\ControllerAdm.php on line 54
```

---

I don't understand this issue : why $_POST is OK, and $_FILES["files"] is not recognized ?
i checked my php.ini, all parameters are set for uploading.

---

**some thoughts :**
- is my MVC framework in cause ? but how could it jam a superglobal variable ?
- i use smoothstate.js, a website page transition plugin, even in admin section.
 It contains AJAX.
- I posted my HTACCESS code, is there a way that it disturbs an $_FILES ?

Really Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved :** smoothstate.js made the $_files getting empty.